# Virtual Host not running http

Tags: https, virtualhost, devserver

I recently restarted my system without any update only to find out that all my virtual host address now points to https and not http, I cant access any of my virtual host address anymore, but can only see it via the localhost address please what could be wrong

Comment: and I found the solution, ....I stopped using .app and .dev and started using .local and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using .dev or .app in your virtualhost, make use of .local or something else, as recent browser updates since Feb 2018 forces .dev and its like tld to https